# Retrieve Existing Details of Mails through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have been using below code in VBA to get the mail contents but i am not able to get all the details.

Could you please help me in getting all the fields (Content Of Mail etc...) for me?

```
With OutlookMAPIFolder.Items(i)
  Range("A" & Trim(Str(RowValue))).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = RowValue - 1
  Range("B" & Trim(Str(RowValue))).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Format(.ReceivedTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
  Range("C" & Trim(Str(RowValue))).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = .Subject
  Range("D" & Trim(Str(RowValue))).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = .Sender
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid you'll need to be more specific. What fields do you want?

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic tip based upon the type of question you've asked:

Add a break point in your code anywhere after OUtlookMAPIFolder has been initialized. In the VBA IDE go to view and display the Locals window. When the code hits your break point navigate to your object in the locals window. You can use the + signs to expand and view all of its properties along with their values. From there, you should be able to determine how to reference the information you want from the item.